# After installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for the first time, my hard drive won't boot windows

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

This is one of my first posts, so forgive me if I do not off as specific as I want to be.

Yesterday, I tired to play my hand with Ubuntu by attempting to have a duel-booted Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/windows 10 system. I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FuLXIKLVjg to guide me through the process even though it was for different version of Ubuntu. I figured the steps would be more or less the same, and even now I believe that it was.

I created a partition for the first time with little knowledge of how it is used, but since the installation required it, I went through allocating space for Ubuntu. After, placing the installation on a flash drive, I restarted my PC and continued with the installation.

I suggest that you refer to the video (@ 8:35) because a visual image would make what I am about to say next more understandable. This was what I would call my first warning sign, because that "Install Ubuntu along side Windows Boot Manager" was not one of my options, so, foolishly, I decided to proceed with the "Something else" option.

The video guide did not cover this section, so I was left with no direction of where to turn to but my own limited knowledge of arranging storage space. As for another visual representation, please go to:
([How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)) because I believe it thoroughly explains what I did and altered.

For the location for the install, I clicked my newly create partition, but it would not let me continue without selecting a "mount point". I selected "/", the first one, and denied the option for a swap area, because in my mind, I believed that the 20 gb space I allocated to it would enough. As you can probably tell, my lack of information guided me to make these rash decisions.

After, the installation was completed, I restarted my PC hoping to get the page where it allows me to choose between Ubuntu and Windows (@ 9:42 of the video), but did not. My computer tried to boot up windows 10 as normal, but the scary thing is, it will not complete the boot. It is stuck on a "loading loop", which even after 10 minutes it continues and does not start windows.

I have a backup disk and a systems repair disk, but my computer does not recognize them -- saying that I should retry and place a system image in the CD-ROM for it to continue. Then, I tried booting windows from a previous state, which I was met with a "the drive where windows is installed is locked" error message. This led me to assume that the problem lies with the changes I made to my hard drive storage, but you guys know better than me.

Please help me fix my PC so that I can load windows normally, and definitely ask me anything if you need any further information.

[Solved]

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Comment: Please don’t add [Solved] to your question. This is a Q&A site, not a simple forum. If any of the answers below has helped you, please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) it. If not, please post your solution as an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a Ubuntu live-usb and select try ubuntu option. Then install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and run it with recommended options. I believe it will fix the problem otherwise post the pastebin link that boot-repair provides here.

Comment: While running boot repair, I received the error message "Grub failed to install to the following devices: /dev/sdb". Should I continue because it warns me that my computer may not start up properly if I do?

Comment: I continued anyway. Here is my pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15552444/. I can now boot into Ubuntu 14.04 and my files seem all to be intact. The problem still remains as my window 10 is not booting. What can I do now? And, thank you for you previous advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update grub through the command in terminal (TTY).

```
sudo update-grub2
```